# Github Actions Docker build: "/pmpn-lock.yaml" and "./nginx/default.conf" not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

So I'm having an issue with my docker build action with github actions and I definitely feel like the issue is obvious but I am failing to get it.

So here is my Github Action

```
name: Build / Publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build-and-push-docker-image:
    name: Build Pinsel Docker image and push to repos
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - 
        name: Checkout codebase
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - 
        name: Docker meta
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v3
        with:
          images: name/app
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=semver,pattern={{version}}
            type=semver,pattern={{major}}.{{minor}}
      # Setup docker build
      - 
        name: Set up Docker buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - 
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - 
        name: Login into Github Packages
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GHCR_PAT }}
      - 
        name: Build image and push it to both registries
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: ../../
          file: ./Dockerfile.prod
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

And here is my Dockerfile located in main directory

```
FROM node:16.4.2-alpine as build
RUN npm install -g pnpm@next-7
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY /pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN pnpm fetch --prod
ADD . ./
RUN pnpm install -r --offline --prod


FROM nginx:1.21-alpine
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and lastly the error

```
#11 [build 5/8] COPY /package.json ./
#11 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref ypf6stpm3t9h2xl6ezvwo7876::kvjk90tcw8wfykmdkvu1uvzgs: "/package.json": not found

#12 [stage-1 2/3] COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
#12 CANCELED
```

```
Dockerfile.prod:13
--------------------
  11 |     
  12 |     FROM nginx:1.21-alpine
  13 | >>> COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  14 |     COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
  15 |     EXPOSE 80
--------------------
error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref ypf6stpm3t9h2xl6ezvwo7876::kvjk90tcw8wfykmdkvu1uvzgs: "/nginx/default.conf": not found
Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref ypf6stpm3t9h2xl6ezvwo7876::kvjk90tcw8wfykmdkvu1uvzgs: "/nginx/default.conf": not found
```

Everything goes well on github actions until it needs to copy files. It says it can't find pnpm-lock.yaml, nor can it find ./nginx both of which are there.

I feel like the answer is super simple and I am just mentally fried and it's not standing out. If I can get a nudge in the right direction, it'd be appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is very likely the context path in the build action. `context: ../../`. Why are you going upwards there? Should you not use `context: ./` ?

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesnt seem to match your error. You dont copy a package.json but the error says `COPY /package.json ./` failed. Are you sure you are showing the right file?

Comment: @TheFool Yea I woke up early this morning with an "omg" moment, once I remembered the purpose of github/checkout. I feel dumb. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that github/checkout puts you at the root directory of the github project, meaning I didn't need to add `../../` for context, I made the mistake of thinking I was navigating from the github action workflow directory.

So for anyone else who ends up this issue: actions/checkout will put you in the root directory of the repo, so you only need to use navigate via context if your dockerfiles are somewhere other than the root folder (like in their own docker folder)